# Spaces between CardView

Tags: android

I am working on a `RecycleView` and `CardView`, but there are spaces between cards that seem are too long, can you show me how to fix it please i have 2 files

**friends_list_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/friendsList"
        >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_below="@+id/username"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_find_friends.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#e6e6e6"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:ignore="TextFields,ContentDescription,UselessParent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchFieldContainer"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchField"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/search_elipses"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_follow_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/friendsList"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please take some screenshots, annotate them to indicate what you consider "spaces between cards that seem are too long" to be, upload them somewhere, and link to them from your question.

Comment: Did you consider removing the padding on the root LinearLayout?   android:padding="16dp" ?

Comment: Whats the use of your Linear layout there?

Comment: "What have you tried?" -The Universe

Comment: yes i tried removing that

Comment: `seem are too long`? the space between 2 cards is apparently twice the horizontal margin, which seems right, given the padding on the linear layout.

Answer (score 4):

the liner layout "android:layout_height="match_parent"" change it to  wrap_content

try it :)

Answer (score 1):

You Only have to change the padding on  the LinearLayout friends_list_item.xml. For example to 8dp

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

the extra space is due to the double padding ... ie there is bottom padding of first element and top padding of second element, which is causing double padding to occur..
solution is to remove padding and apply padding top, padding right and padding left, this way there won't be any double padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Linearlayout padding value 16dp to distance which you want

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >
```